# When using RowsFragment, does ObjectAdapter.setPresenterSelector do anything?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, television, android-tv

I'm using [`RowsFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/RowsFragment.html) with an [`ObjectAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ObjectAdapter.html) and I spotted the method [`ObjectAdapter.setPresenterSelector`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ObjectAdapter.html#setPresenterSelector(android.support.v17.leanback.widget.PresenterSelector)). However, I've already set my [`PresenterSelector`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/PresenterSelector.html) using [`RowsFragment.setPresenterSelector`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/RowsFragment.html#setPresenterSelector(android.support.v17.leanback.widget.PresenterSelector)), so I'm not sure what `ObjectAdapter.setPresenterSelector` does. Does it do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I looked into it and the answer is in the source code of [`ItemBridgeAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ItemBridgeAdapter.html). The method to look up item type contains the following line:

`PresenterSelector presenterSelector = mPresenterSelector != null ?
                mPresenterSelector : mAdapter.getPresenterSelector();`

where `mPresenterSelector` is the thing set by `RowsFragment.setPresenterSelector` and `mAdapter` is the the `ObjectAdapter`. So it looks like they first look at what you called `RowsFragment.setPresenterSelector` with, and if that's null, they then try to use the `ObjectAdapter`'s `PresenterSelector`.